# IE7 & IE8 throwing 404 Error in TTF - font? css?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, http-status-code-404, font-face

> the application i am developing is throwing **404 errors** when the
>   browser is **IE7 or IE8**. But they work in other more recent versions or
>   in other browsers.

**The error is something like this:**

> /PresentationLayer/fonts/MyFontLt.ttf)%20format(%22truetype%22),%20url(fonts/MyFontRg.svg

**In my CSS file is have something like this(working for all browsers, except IE7 & IE8):**

```
    @font-face{
    font-family:'MyBold';
    src:url("fonts/MyFontrgbd-webfont.eot");
    src:url("fonts/MyFontrgbd-webfontd41d.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("fonts/MyFontrgbd-webfont.woff") format("woff"),
    url("fonts/MyFontrgbd-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("fonts/MyFontrgbd-webfont.svg#MyFontBold") format("svg");
    font-weight:400;font-style:normal}


    @font-face{font-family:'MyFontRegular';
    src:url("fonts/MyFontRgd41d.eot");
    src:url("fonts/MyFontRgd41dd41d.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("fonts/MyFontRg.woff") format("woff"),
    url("fonts/MyFontRg.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("fonts/MyFontRg.svg#MyFontRegular") format("svg");
    font-weight:400;font-style:normal}



    @font-face{font-family:'MyFontLight';
    src:url("fonts/MyFontRg.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight:400;font-style:normal}


    @font-face{
    font-family:'MyFontLight';
    src:url("fonts/MyFontLt.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("fonts/MyFontRg.svg#MyFontRegular") format("svg");
    font-weight:400;font-style:normal}
```

**Can anyone help with this issue please?**

**NOTE:**

1. I already tryed Mime-Types
2. The font permissions embedded and also
   installable
3. ...

...

Comment: IE7 and IE8 do not support TTF, just EOT. Do your EOT font files exist?

Comment: Hi, the EOT font files exist! I also tryed to add ** src:url("fonts/MyFontRgd41d.eot");
    src:url("fonts/MyFontRgd41dd41d.eot?#iefix") ** on both ** font-family:'MyFontLight'; ** but with no success. I have the same error

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that the src property of the last `@font-face` rule doesn't contain a supported value. Hence it treats the values as one big url which, obviously, points nowhere.

To fix this just add `url(path/to/example.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),` as the first value of the stack.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting that error is because older versions of IE ( 8,and below) do not support true type fonts format (TTF). As I can see from the error message it only happens with your "Light" font. On inspecting the code , you have EOT font specified in your @font-face for the "regular" and "Bold" versions of the font but not the "light". My suggestion is to create a .EOT version of the "Light" font ( you can do the conversion in any of the many online sites). I have personally used [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator). Place the font file in the directory of choice and add it to your @font-face. [Refer this site here](http://www.stunningcss3.com/resources/fontface-file-types-browser-support.html). That should take care of your problem.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, i tried to add this to the  two last font-face code that i have above:   **src:url("fonts/MyFontrgbd-webfont.eot");
    src:url("fonts/MyFontrgbd-webfontd41d.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),** but it didnt work. I supose creating a new file as you said it wont work either. What do you think?

Comment: @TiagoSilva - this article by Paul Irish should help you big time and make you understand what you have to do. http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/